# Issue with JSON data receiving in paho MQTT

Tags: python, json, client, mqtt, paho

I am trying to publish and subscribe messages in JSON format in python with paho-mqtt.
I am able to publish messages but to subscribe to a specific key value, I am getting many errors. Could you help me find the error and also provide me a solution. I am trying to print the value of method.

code:

```
def subscribe(client: mqtt_client):
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        #print(f"Received `{msg.payload}` from `{msg.topic}` topic") #.decode()
        #topic = msg.topic

        m_decode = str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
        print("data Received type", type(m_decode))
        print("data Received", m_decode)

        m_in = json.loads(m_decode)  # decode json data
        print(type(m_in))
        print("method is = ", m_decode["method"])

    client.subscribe(topic_sub)
    client.on_message = on_message
```

---

The error message is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\try1.py", line 76, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\try1.py", line 73, in run
    client.loop_forever()
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1756, in loop_forever
    rc = self._loop(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1164, in _loop
    rc = self.loop_read()
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1556, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 2439, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 3033, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_publish()
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 3327, in _handle_publish
    self._handle_on_message(message)
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 3570, in _handle_on_message
    on_message(self, self._userdata, message)
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Flask\try1.py", line 35, in on_message
    m_in = json.loads(m_decode)  # decode json data
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Vinod Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What errors? without seeing them all we can do is guess. Edit the question to include the error message.

Comment: The rest of the output from the `on_message` callback would also be useful. The error says what you've tried to parse as JSON is not correctly formatted (the first char is not `{`) so seeing the value of `m_decode` would help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a typo in your code :)

```sh
def subscribe(client: mqtt_client):
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        #print(f"Received `{msg.payload}` from `{msg.topic}` topic") #.decode()
        #topic = msg.topic

        m_decode = str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
        print("data Received type", type(m_decode))
        print("data Received", m_decode)

        m_in = json.loads(m_decode)  # decode json data
        print(type(m_in))
        print("method is = ", m_decode["method"])  # <-- shall be m_in["method"]

    client.subscribe(topic_sub)
    client.on_message = on_message
```

Comment: The error shows that are not getting that far, it's fail to parse the string as a JSON object

Comment: oh, yes, you are right. @hardillb